# Different List Views for Activities & Tasks

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, tasks, list-view, salesforce-classic

I just noticed that you can directly access `Activities` and `Tasks` in Lightning - but no `Events`. The former brings you to a very old Classic list view while the latter is just as expected. I thought that activities were kind of a superset for tasks and events?

You can even see that there are separate list views for different `sObjectTypes`.

```
SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD)
FROM ListView
WHERE SobjectType IN ('Activity', 'Task')
ORDER BY DeveloperName
```

Why are there two separate ways of viewing this in Lightning? Why does Classic seemingly only have activities? Why make this distinction in the first place? What part of this do I not understand?